# Relation between timestamps of files

Tags: files, timestamps

If I am correct:

- `atime` is the last time the file was read/accessed.
- `mtime` is the time when the file content last modified.
- `ctime` is the time when the inode of the file, was last changed.

Questions:

1. If a file's content is stored outside its inode, changing its content will change the mtime to the present, but will that changes its ctime and atime to the present?
2. If we change a file's  attributes stored in its inode, that will change ctime to present, but will that change mtime and atime to present?
3. Does changing anything related to a file such as its content, attributes, or inode, also change atime?

Comment: This is very easy to test...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Celada said, this is really easy to test.

One note however: `ctime` is the last time where inode informations have been changed (the inode number doesn't change).

So:

> 1. If a file's content is stored outside its inode, changing its content will change the mtime to the present, but will that changes its ctime and atime to the present?

If you change content, the `mtime` will change but also the `ctime` because the timestamps of the file (and maybe its size) are updated and those informations are store in inode.

Plus, say this is a text file and you modify its content using `vi`, so the `atime` will also be updated because obviously `vi` will read the file before displaying it.

Example:

```
$ touch file1

$ stat file1
    Access: 2015-05-06 19:11:41.887622158 +0200
    Modify: 2015-05-06 19:11:41.887622158 +0200
    Change: 2015-05-06 19:11:41.887622158 +0200

$ echo "hello" >> file1

$ stat file1
    Access: 2015-05-06 19:11:41.887622158 +0200
    Modify: 2015-05-06 19:12:27.816047883 +0200
    Change: 2015-05-06 19:12:27.816047883 +0200
```

> 2. If we change a file's attributes stored in its inode, that will change ctime to present, but will that change mtime and atime to present?

If you change only file's attribute, only the informations stored in inode change, so yes, only `ctime` will change.

```
$ stat file2
Access: 2015-05-06 19:28:09.378880724 +0200
Modify: 2015-05-06 19:28:09.378880724 +0200
Change: 2015-05-06 19:28:09.378880724 +0200

$ chmod 700 file2

$ stat file2
Access: 2015-05-06 19:28:09.378880724 +0200
Modify: 2015-05-06 19:28:09.378880724 +0200
Change: 2015-05-06 19:30:24.679022346 +0200
```

> 3. Does changing anything related to a file such as its content, attributes, or inode, also change atime?

As I said for the first question, if you don't need to read the file to change those informations, no, `atime` won't change.

Comment: thanks. in your second example, why after chmod, the atime and mtime changes to be earlier?

Comment: @Tim haha :p I did some awful edit before posting to make the change more obvious, but I forgot to edit the first stat... My (very) bad... sorry, I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2):

You need two more sentences:

- `atime` will change only when you read, open, or touch the file.
- `ctime` is also changed when content of file changed.

With these in mind, we can answer your questions easily:

> 1. If a file's content is stored outside its inode, changing its content will change the mtime to the present, but will that changes
>      its ctime and atime to the present?

It will change the `ctime`, not the `atime`.

> 2. If we change a file's attributes stored in its inode, that will change ctime to present, but will that change mtime and atime to
>      present?

No, It doesn't change `mtime` and `atime`

> 3. Does changing anything related to a file such as its content, attributes, or inode, also change atime?
>      No, `atime` only change when you read, open or touch the file.

---

Things to remember:

- `atime` only change when you *read*, *open*, or *touch* the file.
- `ctime` will be updated to the same with `mtime` if `mtime` was updated.
- Changing `ctime` may or may not change `mtime` and don't change `atime`.